# Angular - Some feature routes are not callable

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm working on a Angular8 apps, developing it using feature modules.

I'm facing a route issue on one of my modules loaded via a lazy loading strategy.

This is the very common modules dependency graph used here:
[Dependency Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xl4bP.jpg)

When the apps is running, I have on my side menu the list of artists I subscribed to and the list of their albums as a tree view.
My problem occurs when I want to click on an album using my menu. Clicking on the artist page works but not for the album pages.
When clicking on a album link, the URL is modified in the browser but the page is not loaded.

Here are my routes configurations:

app.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    LoadingBarModule,
    BsDatepickerModule.forRoot(),
    SharedPipesModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    PageNotFoundComponent,
    LoginComponent
  ]
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: '', component: LayoutComponent },
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/login',  pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [ 
        CommonModule,
        CoreModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {enableTracing: true}),

    ],
      exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
```

core-routing.module.ts

```
   const coreRoutes: Routes = [
    { 
        path: '', component: fromComponents.LayoutComponent,
        children: [
            { path: 'music', loadChildren: () => import('./../feature/music/music.module').then(m => m.MusicModule) },
            { path: 'other', loadChildren: () => import('./../feature/other/other.module').then(m => m.OtherModule) },
            { path: 'users', loadChildren: () => import('./../feature/user/user.module').then(m => m.UserModule) },
        ]
    }
   ];

    @NgModule({
        imports: [RouterModule.forChild(coreRoutes)],
        exports: [RouterModule]
    })
```

music-routing.module.ts

```
    const musicRoutes: Routes = [
        {
            path: '', component: fromComponents.RootElementComponent, // <= contains only a <router-outlet>
            children: [
                {   
                    path: ':authorId', pathMatch: 'full', component: fromComponents.AuthorComponent,
                    children: [
                        { path: 'disk/:diskId', pathMatch: 'full', component: fromComponents.DiskComponent }
                    ]   
                }
            ]
        }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(musicRoutes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

An important thing is I would like to conserve albums and artists as a same module.

I don't understand why this is not working because it works for my user module where I have 2 routes :

user/user
user/admin

Many thanks for your help :)

Comment: Shouldn't it be disk/:diskId instead of disk:diskId?

Comment: it should be, yes :) 
After modified the code as you mentionned it displays the PageNotFoundComponent

Comment: Ultimately what URL are you trying to load and it's giving PageNotFound?

Answer (score 0):

> There is a small error in your child's route path syntax
>
> Before

```
children: [
        {   
            path: ':authorId', pathMatch: 'full', component: fromComponents.AuthorComponent,
            children: [
                { path: 'disk:diskId', pathMatch: 'full', component: fromComponents.DiskComponent }
            ]   
        }
    ]
```

> After

```
 children: [
            {   
                path: 'authorId', pathMatch: 'full', component: fromComponents.AuthorComponent,
                children: [
                    { path: 'disk/:diskId', pathMatch: 'full', component: fromComponents.DiskComponent }
                ]   
            }
        ]
```

Comment: Thank you for notice that :)
After correction, it displays my PageNotFoundComponent.

When I hover the link, the browser displays a correct url : music/1/disk/1 but the NotFoundComponent appears.

Comment: Can you modify the other children path as  --->       path: 'authorId'   instead of  path: ':authorId'

you need to remove the (: ) infront of 'authorId'

Comment: Updated the answer, please check

Comment: When I remove the mentioned " : " the author page is not working anymore

Comment: Can you try path: '/:authorId' , if the previous approch is not working